# How to register AutoMapper 4 with Simple Injector 3

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, automapper, simple-injector, automapper-4

I have an Azure web job that parses CSV containing categories and maps the result into regular objects.

I'm trying to replicate AutoMapper + Simple Injector configuration from one project in another by memory but getting an error:

> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException : Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types:
>
> CsvCategory -> Category
>
> WebJobs.Data.CsvCategory -> Data.Category
>
> Destination path:
> Category
>
> Source value:
> WebJobs.Data.CsvCategory

```
container.RegisterSingleton<ITypeMapFactory, TypeMapFactory>();
container.RegisterCollection<IObjectMapper>(MapperRegistry.Mappers);
container.RegisterSingleton<ConfigurationStore>();
container.RegisterSingleton<IConfiguration, ConfigurationStore>();
container.RegisterSingleton<IConfigurationProvider, ConfigurationStore>();
container.RegisterSingleton<IMappingEngine>(Mapper.Engine);

Mapper.Initialize(c =>
{
    c.ConstructServicesUsing(container.GetInstance);
    c.AddProfile<CsvCategoryMappingProfile>();
});

public sealed class CsvCategoryMappingProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure() {
        CreateMap<CsvCategory, Category>();
    }

    public override string ProfileName {
        get { return typeof(CsvCategoryMappingProfile).Name; }
    }
}

public sealed class MappingCategoryConverter : IConverter<CsvCategory, Category>
{
    private readonly IMappingEngine _mapper;

    public MappingCategoryConverter(IMappingEngine mapper)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public Category Convert(CsvCategory category)
    {
        return _mapper.Map<Category>(category);
    }
}
```

I can fix it by replacing the whole container configuration with this line:

```
Mapper.AddProfile<CsvCategoryMappingProfile>();
```

but instead I'd like to learn where is the problem, where I'm doing this wrong.

Comment: You should also register `CsvCategory`

Comment: @Sirwan: I'm receiving AM exception, not SI. Plus CsvCategory isn't constructed by the container, I have instances at the moment of mapping.

Comment: What happens if you call `container.Options.ResolveUnregisteredCollections = true;` directly after creating the `Container`?

Comment: @Steven: Unfortunately no changes.

Comment: I suspect AM misconfiguration. I noticed after calling CreateMap() internal dictionary contains a pair of types. At the moment of mapping this dictionary is empty. This mean I'm dealing with multiple instances.

Comment: What happens woth Simple Injector  2.8.3?

Comment: @Steven: Same. Also same for AM 4.0 and 3.3.

Comment: I'm lost. It's weird because supposed to be obvious.

Comment: Well, at least it's not a b3 breaking change.

Comment: @Steven: No issues with SI v3 so far. Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how to use `Mapper.Initialize()` properly, the obvious way doesn't work.

Here's a workaround:

```
Mapper.Initialize(x =>
{
    var config = container.GetInstance<IConfiguration>();
    config.ConstructServicesUsing(container.GetInstance);
    config.AddProfile<CsvCategoryMappingProfile>();
});
```

Because at `x` you're getting another instance of `IConfiguration`.